# ARToolKit - unable to add NFT marker, unknown marker type

Tags: java, android, artoolkit

I am working with the ARToolKit sample app ARSimple on Android. Instead of having it track the hiro marker, I want to track an NFT marker. So I am using:

```
int testMarker = ARToolKit.getInstance().addMarker("2d;data/nft/Test.jpg");
```

According to the documentation, that is the right way to add an NFT marker (unless I've missed something).

This gives the following output:

```
E/libARWrapper: ARController (native): [error]Error: Unknown marker type '2d' in config '2d;data/nft/Test.jpg'.
E/libARWrapper: ARController (native): [error]Error: Failed to load marker.
```

Which would appear to suggest it is not the right way to do it. So how do I add an NFT marker?

**Edit:**

With the changes from Thor_Bux's answer applied, my code becomes:

```
public boolean configureARScene() {
    pinballMarker = ARToolKit.getInstance().addMarker("nft;data/pinball");

    if (pinballMarker == -1) return false;

    return true;
}
```

The files `pinball.fset`, `pinball.fset3` and `pinball.iset` are located in my `assets/Data` directory.

Error message is now the following:

```
E/libar: Error: unable to open file 'data/pinball.iset' for reading.
E/libar: Error opening file 'data/pinball.iset'.
E/libARWrapper: ARController (native): [error]Error reading data from data/pinball.fset
E/libARWrapper: ARController (native): [error]Error: Failed to load marker.
```

**Edit:**

After uninstalling the app, like Thor_Bux suggested, and changing the configuration to `nft;Data/pinball`, the marker loads. But there is still an error message:

```
E/libARWrapper: ARController (native): [error]Loading Data/pinball.fset.
I/libar: ### Surface No.1 ###
I/libar:   Read ImageSet.
I/libar: Imageset contains 8 images.
D/Camera-JNI: Using callback buffer from queue of length 9
D/Camera-JNI: Using callback buffer from queue of length 8
D/Camera-JNI: Using callback buffer from queue of length 7
D/Camera-JNI: Using callback buffer from queue of length 6
D/Camera-JNI: Using callback buffer from queue of length 5
D/Camera-JNI: Using callback buffer from queue of length 4
D/Camera-JNI: Using callback buffer from queue of length 3
D/Camera-JNI: Using callback buffer from queue of length 2
D/Camera-JNI: Using callback buffer from queue of length 1
D/Camera-JNI: Out of buffers, clearing callback!
I/libar:     end.
I/libar:   Read FeatureSet.
I/libar:     end.
E/libARWrapper: ARController (native): [info]First NFT marker added; enabling NFT marker detection.
E/libARWrapper: ARController (native): [info]Added marker (UID=0), total markers loaded: 1.
```

Even though the marker appears to have loaded successfully it is not detected with `queryMarkerVisible()`. Furthermore it seems `SimpleRenderer#draw()` is never called despite the scene being configured successfully.

Comment: ARToolKit5 or ARToolKit6?

Comment: ARToolKit5. I've been unable to get into the beta for ARToolKit6.

Comment: Artk5 does not support jpg. You need to create fset and iset files per nft marker using the providet tools. I can note a detailed solution tomorrow.

Comment: I have generated those. What I need is a way to create a marker from them. I would be most grateful for a detailed solution to that; you can leave out creating the fset and iset files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the previous conversation it looks like you are working with this example code and want to change this line of code to make it track NFT markers:
https://github.com/artoolkitx/artoolkit5/blob/master/AndroidStudioProjects/ARSimpleProj/aRSimple/src/main/java/org/artoolkit/ar/samples/ARSimple/SimpleRenderer.java#L72

You also state that you already created the needed NFT .fset and .iset files as described here: https://archive.artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=3_Marker_Training:marker_nft_training

What you now need to do is to add the fset and iset files into the 'assets/Data/' directory of your project. (Right next to the hiro.patt)

Then you change the mentioned line of code to this:
`nft;data/pinball`
Which is documented here:

https://github.com/artoolkitx/artoolkit5/blob/master/AndroidStudioProjects/ARBaseLibProj/aRBaseLib/src/main/java/org/artoolkit/ar/base/ARToolKit.java#L303

and

https://github.com/artoolkitx/artoolkit5/blob/master/lib/SRC/ARWrapper/ARMarker.cpp#L239

Hope that helps

Comment: Now I get another error: E/libar: Error: unable to open file 'data/pinball.iset' for reading.
E/libar: Error opening file 'data/pinball.iset'.
E/libARWrapper: ARController (native): [error]Error reading data from data/pinball.fset
E/libARWrapper: ARController (native): [error]Error: Failed to load marker.

Comment: Can you please add your new configuration and error to you question marked as edit. Then others can follow up as well. To help you further I'd need to see how your code looks like now.

Comment: Android is caching the assets dir and sometimes not updating. Remove the app from your phone and try again. Check the the path is correct

Comment: Uninstalling the app helped, but I had to change `nft;data/pinball` to `nft;Data/pinball` as well. Still does not work properly, updated question. @Thor_Bux